# how to pass data from recyclerview on item clicked in Xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin.android

I want to launch a new activity with detailed information upon recyclerview item clicked

```
  private void OnItemClick(object sender, AluminiAdapterClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(Activity, typeof(MovieDetailPage));
            //Toast.MakeText(Activity, "This is photo number " + , ToastLength.Short).Show();
            intent.PutExtra("MovieDetail", e.ItemId);
            //intent.PutExtra("Title", e.Title);
            //intent.PutExtra("Category", e.Category);
            //intent.PutExtra("Discription", e.Discription);
            //intent.PutExtra("Image", e.Image);
            //intent.PutExtra("Amount", e.Amount);
            //intent.PutExtra("Showing_Time", e.Showing_Time);
            StartActivity(intent);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, if you want to pass some string or int value from activity to another activity, you can just use the following code:

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity2));    
    intent.PutExtra("MyData", "Data from Activity1");    
    StartActivity(intent);
```

If you want to pass custom object to another activity, you need to use JSON.Net package that you can install with Nuget Manager. By using JSON you can serialize your object in first activity and then deserialize in the second activity.

Activity1:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

void mBtnSignIn_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
 {
  User user = new User();
  user.Name = "John";
  user.Password = "password";

  Intent intent = new Intent(this,typeof(Activity2));
  intent.PutExtra("User",JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));
  this.StartActivity(intent);
```

}

Activity2:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

 private User user;
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Activity2);
    user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(Intent.GetStringExtra("User"));
 }
```